# How to write "between" and "until" to extract integers from a text file?

Tags: python, text

I have a lot of lines like below:

```
_:9:_:SER _ 9 SER S 3 0.000 66.878  
_:11:_:LEU _ 11 LEU E 8 0.000 67.168    
_:108:_:ARG _ 108 ARG   1 0.000 62.398
```

Each item is separated by a space. Because different lines have different numbers (e.g. `9`, `11`, `108`), the subsequent values are not aligned at the same column positions. In the 3rd line, there are 3 spaces between `ARG` and `1` because this line does not have that information so a space is used to fill it.

I need to extract two pieces of information

1. the `9`, `11`, `108` values at 1st, 2nd and 3rd lines, respectively
2. the `3`, `8`, `1` values (before the `0.000`) at 1st, 2nd and 3rd lines, respectively

I want to use python to write a generalised script to extract that information, instead of a lengthy `if-then loop` to consider one-digit, two-digit and three-digit cases individually.

My idea is something like this:

1. extract the integer values between the first and the second `:`
2. extract the integer values after the 5th space, until another space is detected after that value.

Comment: Is there a letter missing on the `ARG` line? Or does the extra space indicate that the field is missing?

Comment: the extra space indicates that field is missing. i.e. that line does not have that property, so use a space to fill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get each line as a string, you can do this:

```
your_line = "_:108:_:ARG _ 108 ARG   1 0.000 62.398"
splitted = your_line.split()
# splitted = ['_:108:_:ARG', '_', '108', 'ARG', '1', '0.000', '62.398']
```

Essentially, it makes a list of strings from the original list, delimited by the character you put in. If you don't give `split()` an argument then it just splits the string on any whitespace.

Now you can easily extract the information you want:

```
info1 = splitted[2]
info2 = splitted[4]
```

Comment: But for the 1st and 2nd lines, it needs to use `splitted[5]` instead of `splitted[4]`. How to generalised it?

Comment: You could check whether that single-character `S` or `E` or whatever was in `splitted[4]` (i.e. check if `splitted[4]` is not an integer) and if so then use `splitted[5]` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are only extracting numeric fields, you can use the regular expression `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, which reads **digits, then maybe a period and more digits**.

Then you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to grab the numeric fields as a list, and then work with them.

```
>>> fields = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?', lines[0])
>>> fields
['9', '9', '3', '0.000', '66.878']
>>> (fields[0], fields[2])
('9', '3')
```

Comment: It seems to be the way, could you please show me how to do it exactly? What do you mean by `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` ?

Comment: That is the pattern for the regular expression. You can read the documentation on Python regular expressions at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: This is a pattern to recognize an integer or a float. `\d` means a digit,  `+` means one or more, `(?: )` means that the contents shouldn't be captured separately, `\.` is a literal `.`, `*` means any number, and `?` means optional. So, a __string of digits that are optionally followed by `.` and then more digits__.